# Email Attachments using php mail() function - Working for gmail but not working for yahoo

Tags: php

I have used the below code for sending the mail with attachments. It's receiving the mail fine for us in gmail account but in yahoo account that the mail is not received. Please refer the below code,

```
<?php 
    $my_file = "fb_icon_hover.png";
    $my_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/poc/mailChecking/";
    $my_name = "ETU";
    //$my_mail = "abibith@gmail.com";
    $my_mail = "abibith@gmail.com";
    //$my_replyto = "arul.it02@gmail.com";
    $mail_data      =   file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/poc/mailChecking/postajob_mailcontent.html");
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{COMPANY_NAME}',"Testing Company", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{JOB_NAME}',"Testing jobname", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{EMAIL}',"abibith@gmail.com", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{JOB_POSITION}',"Software Engineer", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{JOBTYPE}',"Programmer", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{PHONE}',"04132660407", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{ADDRESS}',"Testing Address", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{CITY}',"Testing City", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{STATE}',"Testing State", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{POSTCODE}',"605004", $mail_data);
    $mail_data      =   str_replace('{JOB_DESCRIPTION}',"This is a testing Job", $mail_data);
    /*echo "====>".$mail_data;
    die();*/
    $my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
    //$my_message = "Hallo,\r\ndo you like this script? I hope it will help.\r\n\r\ngr. Olaf";
    $my_message = $mail_data;
    mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "abibith@gmail.com", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_subject, $my_message);
    function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $subject, $message) {
        $file = $path.$filename;
        $file_size = filesize($file);
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $name = basename($file);
        $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
        //$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."--";
        if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
            echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
        } else {
            echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        }
    }
?>
```

So kindly assist our request and do the needful.

Thanks,

Arularasan D,

Senior Programmer.

Comment: have you checked in spam folder of yahoo.

Comment: The email is not received or the attachment is broken? These are completely different problems.

Comment: For one thing, you're calling your `mail_attachment()` function before it's declared. Plus, I don't know how you're using it for `mail()`. There's no email assigned to `$mailto`

Comment: @Fred-ii- - You can declare a function at any point in a script; like Javascript, they are parsed before the code is executed.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Really? I've had problems like that before. Bizarro.

Comment: [Umm...](http://codepad.org/zspTsvTm) And: [*Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, except when a function is conditionally defined as shown in the two examples below.*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: I have not received the mail in the yahoo and also checked the spam folder. Mail is not received in yahoo but in gmail is working fine for us with attachments.

Answer (score 1):

```
$to = "myemail@mydomain.com";
$from = "Website <website@mydomain.com>";
$subject = "Test Attachment Email";

$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "document.pdf";

//$pdfdoc is PDF generated by FPDF
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK";
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR";
}
```

Had same problem. But later formed code like in upper example (thanks Alin Purcaru for it) and problem was solved. Hope it helps mate )